# PHP Pass by Reference to Function for Same Object in Class

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

I am trying to modify an object that has been created by passing it from the class to another function.  In my scenario below, I am would expect the result to be 2, but I am getting an "Uncaught Error".

```
------------------------------
Index.php
------------------------------
include "class.php";
include "function.php";

$number = new a();

$number->add(1);
echo $number->display();

$number->add_helper();
echo $number->display();

------------------------------
function.php
------------------------------
function get_help(&$numb) {
    $numb->add(1);
}

------------------------------
class.php
------------------------------

class a {

    protected $var;

    public function add($numb) {
        $this->var .= $numb;
    }

    public function display() {
        return $this->var;
    }

    public function add_helper() {
        get_help($this->var);
    }
}

------------------------------
```

When I run the add_helper function, that is where errors happen.  I an expecting the result to be 2.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Will

Comment: `add_helper()` isn't a function in the global namespace, it's a class method and can't be called in it's own like that. It needs to be called on the instance of that class. `$a->add_helper();`

Comment: Also, this would never give you `2`, it would give you `11` since you're just concatenating the numbers as strings. If you want to add the number, it should be `$this->var += $numb:`. You should also set a default value: `protected $var = 0;` (even if it works without doing it, it's good practice).

Comment: Your `get_help()` expects the argument to be an object (since you use it as an object in the function) but you're passing the value of `var` (which is a string). If you want to do what you're doing, then you should change it to: `get_help($this);`. Then you can also remove `&` from the get_help() signature since objects are passed as reference by default.

Comment: You should also post the _full_ error message since it contains more info about where and why it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Magnus Eriksson's response...

I was passing the string when I needed to be passing the object.

the add_helper function in my a class should actually be:

```
    get_help($this);
```

instead of $this->var.

Thank you Magnus.